# Suppose $G$ is a group, $a,b \in G$ such that $ab^{3}a^{-1} = b^2, b^{-1}a^2b=a^3$ then $ab=e$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group, $a,b \in G$ such that $ab^{3}a^{-1} = b^2, b^{-1}a^2b=a^3$ then $ab=e$

Any clue?

Comment: I don't think this is true: If I suppose that $ab=e$ is true, I can deduce that $a=b=e$.

Comment: I can get $a=b^3=e$ but not $ab=e$.

Comment: I get have the same result as @Kusma. Are you sure you typed all the exponents in the question correctly?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis can u pls have a look now?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this?

Comment: Did you try anything to solve this?

Comment: tried but lost.... relation is symmetry ... messed up completely

Answer (score 2):

I do not think your result is correct.

By substituting $a^3$ from equation (2) into equation (1)
\begin{align*}
a^3b^{-1}a^{-1}&=b^2\\
(b^{-1}a^2b)b^{-1}a^{-1}&=b^2\\
b^{-1}a&=b^2\\
a&=b^3
\end{align*}

Again substitute the equation obtained into equation (1)
\begin{align*}
b^5&=b^2\\
b^3&=e
\end{align*}
Hence $a=e$. But substitute $a=e$ into both equations we can only get $b^{-1}=b^2$ and $b^{-1}b=e$. So information is not enough to obtain $ab=e$.

Comment: can u pls have a look now?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is a variation of the following standard exercise: the group $G$ with presentation
$$
\langle a,b\mid ab^2a^{-1}=b^3, ba^2b^{-1}=a^3\rangle
$$
is the trivial group. So $a=b=e$ and $ab=e$.

Here is the proof:
From the two relations we immediately have $(1),(2)$:
\begin{align}
b & = a^{-3}ba^2, \\
b^3 & =ab^2a^{-1}. 
\end{align}
Squaring and cubing $(2)$ we obtain $(3),(4)$:
\begin{align}
b^6 & = ab^4a^{-1}, \\
b^9 & =ab^6a^{-1}. 
\end{align}
Now we claim that $(5)$
\begin{align}
b^4 & = a^{-1}b^4a. 
\end{align}
This would imply $b^6\overset{\text{(3)}}{=}ab^4a^{-1}=b^4$, and hence $b^2=e$.
Then $(2)$ would imply $b^2=e$, and $b^3=e$ by $(2)$, so that $b=e$, and also $a=e$.

So let us prove $(5)$:
\begin{align*}
b^4 & = b\cdot b^4\cdot b^{-1} \\
    & \overset{\text{(1)}}{=} (a^{-3}ba^2)\cdot b^4\cdot (a^{-2}b^{-1}a^3) \\
    & = (a^{-3}ba)\cdot (ab^4a^{-1})\cdot (a^{-1}b^{-1}a^3) \\
    &  \overset{\text{(3)}}{=}(a^{-3}b)\cdot (ab^6a^{-1})\cdot (b^{-1}a^3)\\
    &  \overset{\text{(4)}}{=} (a^{-3}b)\cdot b^9\cdot (b^{-1}a^3)\\
    & = a^{-3}\cdot b^9\cdot a^3 \\
    &  \overset{\text{(4)}}{=}  a^{-3}\cdot (ab^6a^{-1})\cdot a^3 \\
    & = a^{-2}\cdot b^6\cdot a^2 \\
    & \overset{\text{(3)}}{=}  a^{-2}\cdot (ab^4a^{-1})\cdot a^2 \\
    & = a^{-1}b^4a.
\end{align*}

Comment: can u pls tell me how to prove this a trivial group? because of symmetry i am getting again the same forms